# this.mobilityService.currentMessage.subscribe is not a function in angular unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable, karma-runner

In karma unit testing I'm getting this.mobilityService.currentMessage.subscribe is not a function error

below is the .ts file where I'm trying to get the values from another component through service

```
  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService, private teamService: TeamserviceService) {this.getData()}

getData(){
this.projectService.currentMessage.subscribe(data => {
  if(data!=null)
  {
    this.serviceName=data.service_object.serviceName;
    this.serviceId = data.service_object.id})
```

this is how my service code looks like -

```
messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
getProjectList(messageSource: string[]) {
this.messageSource.next(messageSource);
}
 constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
 getAllProjectService(teamid,serviceid){
 return this.http.get(environment.TEST_AUTOMATION_ENDPOINT+'/api/projects-by-team-and-servicestore? 
teamId='+teamid+'&serviceStoreId='+serviceid+'&access_token='+this.decaccesstoken);
 }
 }
```

My .spec file I'm creating a spy object like this -

```
  const mockProjectService= jasmine.createSpyObj('projectService', ['getAllProjectService','currentMessage']);
```

Since 'currentMessage' is not a method inside the service I get this error. Any idea how to subscribe to a variable inside of a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your service code to:

```
messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);

currentMessage() {
    return this.messageSource.asObservable();
}
getProjectList(messageSource: string[]) {
      this.messageSource.next(messageSource);
}
 constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
 getAllProjectService(teamid,serviceid){
       return this.http.get(environment.TEST_AUTOMATION_ENDPOINT+'/api/projects-by-team- 
       and-servicestore?teamId='+teamid+'&serviceStoreId='+serviceid+'&access_token='+this.decaccesstoken);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for ur reply but I'm still getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined error

Comment: In getData() method
```this.projectService.currentMessage()``` is method

Comment: ok it worked because I had not written returnvalue in .spec file so it was throwing error. Thanks for the answer.